# What is the meaning of "P's in the ends"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Moses came to buy weed from Hi-Hatz in exchange of Alien he found.
& also Moses harassed one woman in streets with masked-on.

> Hi-Hatz: You shot my food from Ron still?
>
> Moses: Sometimes.
>
> Hi-Hatz: There's better ways to make **P's in the ends**, you know. Man of
>   your age should  step his game up. Move some white. I'm gonna put you
>   on bail.

<sup>(Source : [Attack the Block](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1478964/) )</sup>

When I google **P's in the ends** it shows words ends with P, but here context is different to define it.

What is the meaning of "P's in the ends"?

Comment: I assume the sentence means "There are more efficient strategies which will lead to your procurement of **shekels in the surrounding area**."

Comment: P = pounds, the ends = this neighborhood or the neighborhoods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ends" is London slang derived from Jamaican Patois for a neighborhood, ghetto, or simply "the streets".

"P's" is the shortened form of "pounds", which is British currency.

Here's the translated version of what the two are saying:

> Hi-Hatz: You sell my weed from Ron still?
>
> Moses: Sometimes.
>
> Hi-Hatz: There are better ways to make money in the streets, you know. A man of your age should step his game up. Sell some cocaine. I'm going to put you on bail.